# Creating a question box

Tags: framed

We are writing a book for kids, and it has some question & answer boxes like the following,

[image]

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Is there any built-in command for this purpose? Or should I create a box and put my text into this box along with a `questionMark.eps`?

Since I'm going to use this very often, I want to make a shortcut too. Something like the following,

```
\questionBox{Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum?}
```

Comment: You have to create a new box. However, how big should the question mark be?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel A fixed height, not dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[
linewidth=1pt,
innerrightmargin=80pt,
singleextra={
  \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in
  node[xshift=-40pt] at (P|-0,0.5*\y1+0.5*\y2) 
    {\includegraphics[width=60pt]{QM}};
}
]{Qbox}

\newcommand\questionbox[1]{%
  \begin{Qbox}#1\end{Qbox}}

\begin{document}

\questionbox{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's an option using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{Qbox}{
enhanced,
sidebyside,
righthand width=60pt,
colback=white,
overlay={\node[xshift=-40pt] at (frame.east) 
  {\includegraphics[width=60pt]{QM}};
  }
}

\newcommand\questionbox[1]{%
  \begin{Qbox}#1\end{Qbox}}

\begin{document}

\questionbox{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option lower `separated=false` suppresses the dashed line.

Comment: You were too fast ;-)

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @zagy You're welcome! I updated my answer with another option.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You are faster than light ;-) By the way, to remove the dashed line (if wished) in your `tcolorbox` example, you could use the brand-new option `lower separated=false`.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm ah, I was just looking for that option.  Although I like the dashed line in the example, I'll add a comment on how to suppress it to my answer. Thanks.